# Отображение гистограммы и графика распределения псевдослучайных чисел

Tags: python, matplotlib

Всем доброго времени суток, возникла такая задача, надо реализовать датчик псевдослучайных величин для функции плотности вероятности на интервале [a,b], и для проверки необходимо построить гистограмму случайных величин. Собственно сам код несложный, набросал получилось так:

```
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def func(x): #функция
    return 6 * pow(x, 2) + 4*x - 3

def func_F(e, V):
    return 2 * pow(e, 3) + 2*pow(e, 2) - 3*e - 1 - 147 * V

def nyuton(a, b, V): #метод ньютона
    eps = 0.0001
    if (func_F(a, V) * func_F(b, V > 0)):
        c = a
    else:
        c = b
    while abs(func_F(c, V)) >= eps:
        c = c - func_F(c, V)/func(c)

    return c

def main():
    xmin = 1
    xmax = 4
    dx = 0.1
    N = 10000
    a = []
    for i in range(N):
        a.append(nyuton(xmin, xmax, random.random()))

    xlist = mlab.frange(xmin, xmax, dx)
    ylist = [func(x) for x in xlist]

    plt.plot(xlist, ylist)
    plt.hist(a, 20)
    plt.show()

main()
```

И дальше сама проблема, если по X и график, и гистограмма выводятся правильно, то по Y, выводится количество попаданий чисел в столбец гистограммы, что при больших N намного превышает значение функции и получается такая картина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы гистограмма "подстраивалась" под функцию и по Y выдавало значение функции?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать вторую ось Y. Как-то так:

```
def main():
    xmin = 1
    xmax = 4
    dx = 0.1
    N = 10000
    a = []
    for i in range(N):
        a.append(nyuton(xmin, xmax, random.random()))

    xlist = mlab.frange(xmin, xmax, dx)
    ylist = [func(x) for x in xlist]

    plt.plot(xlist, ylist)
    plt2 = plt.twinx()
    plt2.hist(a, 20)
    plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]